# In Siege Mode, how can I destroy the battleship without the anti-aircraft?

Tags: hawken

In the [Siege Mode](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TO2swuOOHac), I saw players destroying our battleship while we had control of the anti-aircraft.
Are there other hidden weapons that can help to destroy the battleship ?  Or is just possible to destroy it with the mech's weapons (and in that case, how) ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer on [the (interesting) ING Hawken tips page](http://www.ign.com/wikis/hawken/Tips):

> In a worst case scenario, you can shoot the battleship yourself. To take it down you have to take out the engines.  However, the battleship has turrets and shooting these off is often a prerequisite because they will shoot you back.  Shooting down the battleship is a
>   lot of work, much better to get the AA.

The engines are these green glowing plates below the ship (you can see it on the question's picture and the [Lyrion's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/101669/15726)).  Each of those has its own life gauge, so yeah, it might take a while.  But it's possible !

Answer (score 1):

I am going to answer by just my own findings. It is indeed possible to destroy the gunship. On the screenshots I have posted the engine is circled in Red, if you look closely it sais 5x next to the health bar. The gunship starts with 10x, this means you need to shoot down the engines health bar 10 times to kill it. The blue circles are the turrets, now I can't remember where they all are but there is still one left, and one just got destroyed on the left. You don't need to destroy them but they will fire upon you and hurt like hell.

[image: Gunship]